# Why does hashCode() return zero before items are added to HashMap?

Tags: java

```
Map map = new HashMap();
System.out.println("hashCode:"+map.hashCode()); //hashcode==0 why?

map.put("test","test");
System.out.println("hashCode:"+map.hashCode()); //hashcode be okay here
```

How can I get hashCode after `Map map = new HashMap();` ? (like: `new Object().hashCode()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashCode for maps is defined as the sum of all hashcodes of the keys and values.

More precisely, [Map.hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#hashCode%28%29) is specified as:

> Returns the hash code value for this map. The hash code of a map is defined to
>   be the sum of the hash codes of each entry in the map's `entrySet()` view.
>   This ensures that `m1.equals(m2)` implies that `m1.hashCode()==m2.hashCode()` for any
>   two maps m1 and m2, as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode()`.

And [Map.Entry.hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode%28%29) is defined as

> Returns the hash code value for this map entry. The hash code of a map entry `e` is defined to be:
>
> ```
> (e.getKey()==null   ? 0 : e.getKey().hashCode()) ^
> (e.getValue()==null ? 0 : e.getValue().hashCode())
> ```
>
> This ensures that `e1.equals(e2)` implies that `e1.hashCode()==e2.hashCode()` for any two
>   Entries `e1` and `e2`, as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode`.

Your new map has no entries yet, thus the sum is 0. Everything is at is should be.

If you want a number like the unoverridden `Object.hashCode()` would return, use `System.identityHashCode(map)`. This is a (more or less unique) number for each map, which will not change when the contents of the map changes.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode%28%29):

> **The hash code of a map is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of each
>   entry in the map's entrySet() view.**
>   This ensures that m1.equals(m2)
>   implies that
>   m1.hashCode()==m2.hashCode() for any
>   two maps m1 and m2, as required by the
>   general contract of Object.hashCode().

Since your HashMap (which is derived from AbstractMap) is initially empty, that sum is zero.

Comment: I think this is a serious flaw in the Java specification and implementation. Just imagine a `HashSet` of `HashMaps`. You add a map to the set, add an entry to the map, and you'll never find your map in the set again :-(.

Comment: @Carsten: Generally, don't use mutable objects as keys for maps (or sets) ... or at least, don't mutate them as long as they are keys.

Comment: @Paŭlo This is probably feasible for most Map use cases, but to require this for Sets is quite a restriction.

Comment: (Carsten: This is getting a bit off topic here - maybe we should continue in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)?) I'm not really sure how you would want to access the map in the set - by identity or by equality? You can still use the set's iterator, independent of any changes. Maybe some non-hashbased structure would be better.

Comment: the hashCode definition of Map is just fine. Anyone who tries to make assumptions in the direction a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() --> a.equals(b);  needs to read up on hashCodes